# android camera2 createCaptureSession deprecated

Tags: android, android-camera2

CameraDevice.createCaptureSession is mostly deprecated. Any example on how to use the left over version method with the SessionConfiguration argument (and there especially the executor argument), would be nice.

Currently I have:

```
cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaceList, mCameraSessionListener, mCameraHandler);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not want to use any executor capabilites you can use a HandlerExecutor:

```
SessionConfiguration sessionConfiguration = new SessionConfiguration(SessionConfiguration.SESSION_REGULAR, Collections.singletonList(outputConfiguration), new HandlerExecutor(mCameraHandler.getLooper()), mCameraSessionListener);
cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(sessionConfiguration);
```